# Dirichlet series and analytic properties of w(n)

Tags: convergence-divergence, analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-series

w(n)=v(n) is the number of distinct prime factors of n.
**i have found Its Dirichlet Series and Abscissa of Convergence from Apostol's book.**

**Proof**. Let $a_{n}$ indicate whether $n$ is prime. For $\sigma>1$

\begin{aligned}
\zeta(s) \sum_{p} \frac{1}{p^{s}} &=\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{s}}\right)\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_{n}}{n^{s}}\right) \\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{s}} \sum_{d | n} a_{n} \\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{s}} \sum_{p | n} 1 \\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\nu(n)}{n^{s}}
\end{aligned}

When I search this arithmetic function , i also read from Titshmarch and Montgomery's Books; $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \omega(n) n^{-s}=\zeta(s) \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}{n} \log \zeta(n s)$ =$\zeta(s) \sum_{p} \frac{1}{p^{s}}$

So; My little 2 questions are  **How can we prove that equality?**

**And i am also curious about abscissa of  Absolute convergence**. What about it?
You can also give some good referrences (books,article,hints,the books solutions, pdf-examples etc) to me about the Dirichlet series and their Analytic properties.
Thanks for your answers.

Comment: $\sum_p p^{-s}$ doesn't converge absolutely if $\Re(s) \le 1$ thus neither does $\sum_n n^{-s}\sum_{p|n}1$. For $\Re(s) > 1$, both $\zeta(s),\sum_p p^{-s}$ converge absolutely thus so does the product. What else is unclear to you ?

Comment: its very clear answer. thanks